# Looking for a mid 2000's children's fantasy book

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read a book in 2007-2009 in my primary school library in Australia. I remember it being a children's fantasy series, but it's possible it was one book or meant for older audiences.

It started with a boy in a village that had remnants of technology that didn't work—he describes a light bulb as a glass pear, and there's a TV set that doesn't work. A girl comes from somewhere else (maybe over the mountain?) and she knows about technology. The girls name was possibly Mara or something similar.

The boy and the girl go on a journey away from the village. At one point one of the kids is fed a peanut butter sandwich, but it's a magical trick and they're actually eating their friend. This is a bit confusing but it wasn't that their friend was dead and the meat had been transformed to look like a sandwich. The sandwich was like a magical proxy for the friend, and by eating it the kid was killing their friend. One of the kids also takes the form of a bird at one point—I can't remember if they are turned into a bird by an antagonist or if it's voluntary.

Towards the end of the story they end up in a cabin in the woods. It was quite cosmic and dark.

I vaguely remember the cover being red gradient and the title potentially having "Sparrow" in it, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Pretty sure it's not the tripods!

I know it's not heaps to go on but I can't remember anything else. It was in a school library so seems unlikely it was adult fiction.

Comment: Most YA books don't have outright cannibalism, even in an apocalyptic setting.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add, for example what was the name of the main character? What was the name of his girlfriend? Was he attracted to her or were they just companions? What was her name? What did she look like? How old was the boy? Was the girl older or younger than him? Why had society collapsed? Why did she run away from her village? How were they tricked into thinking meat was a PB&J? Where were the books set?